# Search addresses by user input using postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I have hierarchical table with addresses using adjacency list. I can freely add any type of column to this table by now.
Suppose I have hierarchical data in the table with the depth of 4 (Country, City, Street, House Number), so one of the leaf has this denormalized address:

> Russia, Perm, Altayskaya st., 25

So, user must get this row, when he inputs these strings:

1. perm altayskaya 25
2. altayskaya, building 25
3. altayskaya 25 perm
4. 25
5. and so on...

I can store this denormalized string, or array with set of tokens, or smth. else. But I need to be able to search by inaccurate queries.

Comment: Sounds like an applikation for full text search (with a simple dictionary and custom stop words).

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, yes, it sounds, but i don't need natural language rules and any other forms of world. Dictionary is this table (any token in address is the name from one row )

Comment: @Neka you need to create custom text search configuration https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-configuration.html that will suite your needs and will not do stemming etc